# Why isn't ['field_name'][0]['#markup'] work for getting taxonomy of this node?

Tags: nodes, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have two content types: Case and News.
In node--case.tpl.php, I'm using `echo $content['field_case_category'][0]['#markup'];` in order to print the taxonomy term for the page and that works fine. In node--news.tpl.php, I can't use `echo $content['field_news_category'][0]['#markup'];`; in fact, #markup is not even present in this array at all.

1. Why doesn't this method work in the second case? What can I do to solve it?
2. Is there a better/right way to print taxonomy terms in nodes?

The error I get is the following:

> Notice: Undefined index: #markup in include()

Comment: Sounds as if there is currently no term set in the node you are checking. Is this possible? Then you'ld maybe have to check `isset()` and `!empty()` first.

Comment: The two pages are built _exactly_ the same way, so that shouldn't be it if I understand you correctly?

Comment: A field could be empty; that doesn't depend from how the pages are built, but from the content a field has for a specific node.

Comment: They're set up the same way. If I can render the field without _any_ markup now I'm set.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't print some result directly. You should print the content of field like below.

```
print drupal_render($content['field_case_category']);
```

Hope this solves your problem. Also please check whether your node contains the value for the field_case_category field.

Comment: Yeah, this will work, but it also renders additional divs, does it not? I need to get the taxonomy term in plain text – is that possible with that method?

Comment: You can set taxonomy term display as plain text using the manage display section of the specific content type. Also, is that node have some data within that field?

Comment: I've already set it to display as plain text instead of a link. But there's still additional divs rendered around the plain text content.

Comment: Sometimes the #markup not have content in it. So, you should use drupal_render for rendering the field and strip out the tags using some php function like strip_tags($str);

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to render a field API field is using [`render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/render/7) (`print render($content['field_case_category'])` or `print render($content['field_news_category'])`) that, through [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7), is able to correctly handle all the cases, including the case #markup is not set because the field is empty.

Notice that you don't normally need to explicitly print node fields, if not in the case you hide them before calling `render($content)`, and then you need to render them separately. The default node.tpl.php file used from the Node module, or any theme that comes with Drupal.

```
// node/node.tpl.php
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <?php print $user_picture; ?>

  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

  <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
    <div class="submitted">
      <?php print $submitted; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php
      // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      print render($content);
    ?>
  </div>

  <?php print render($content['links']); ?>

  <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>

</div>
```

```
//bartik/templates/node.tpl.php
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
      <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
    </h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

  <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
    <div class="meta submitted">
      <?php print $user_picture; ?>
      <?php print $submitted; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="content clearfix"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php
      // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      print render($content);
    ?>
  </div>

  <?php
    // Remove the "Add new comment" link on the teaser page or if the comment
    // form is being displayed on the same page.
    if ($teaser || !empty($content['comments']['comment_form'])) {
      unset($content['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']);
    }
    // Only display the wrapper div if there are links.
    $links = render($content['links']);
    if ($links):
  ?>
    <div class="link-wrapper">
      <?php print $links; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>

</div>
```

If your template is already using `render($content)`, and you are not seeing the taxonomy terms, then you need to check the field has not been hidden in the display setting, or a module is hiding it.

Comment: Thanks. Render does work, but is there a way to print _only_ the string itself? As in no additional markup, <a> or <div> etc? Setting the format to plain text isn't enough to remove the surrounding divs it seems.